# How can I access the version number of the Google Maps API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Does the Google Maps Javascript API have a property/method that returns its exact version number?

I need this info for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 20):

To acccess exact version of Google Maps API one can check **google.maps.version**

Answer (score 2):

When you include Google Maps API you can choose version of it. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=LONG_KEY_HERE"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    google.load('maps', '2');
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Here we want to use version 2 of Google Maps API.

Comment: google.load('maps', '2.1'), for example :) or any other versions

Comment: what if i am using an npm package (@googlemaps/js-api-loader) to dynamically load in the API, how can i then check what version it loads in?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the [`G_API_VERSION`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#G_API_VERSION) could do :

> This constant specifies the version of
>   the API currently being served to your
>   page.

I've just tested on two sites, and it contained things like `"193c"` and `"140g"`.

Comment: not exactly what I want... it should report something like v2.3.1 (like the version you request in the script tag). Do you know if i can deduct the "official" version from the G_API_VERSION key?

Answer (score 0):

In the Maps API v2, G_API_VERSION is what you want. For example, 193c means its loading v2.193c, 140g means 2.140g.

Changelog is here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIChangelog